# Installing FFmpeg 1.1.2 "Fire Flower" on a mountain Lion

Tags: macos, compilation, ffmpeg, command, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to install FFmpeg 1.1.2 "Fire Flower" on mountain lion machine. 
I downloaded http://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-1.1.2.tar.bz2 from http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html and extracted it. 
Is there a step by step tutorial to get the source code compiled, installed and get it running in my machine

Comment: just two commands did the job :
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
brew install ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

There are verbose compile instructions in the [FFmpeg wiki](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki): [FFmpeg: OS X Compilation Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide).

Answer (score 0):

just two commands did the job : 
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"; 
brew install ffmpeg